# Embedding Console application and scheduling in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I have a console application that scrapes from different sites and update data in SQL Server, currently, it works on a physical server and is scheduled to run once a day.
We want to start using existing functions in Azure without the need for VM setup.

We thought about using WebJobs but we wonder if this solution can be effective for us.
(We do it without using selenium, without using any web browser)

Comment: How long does the process take?

Comment: Around 1 hour all processes.

Comment: If you can wrap that in a Docker container you could use Azure Container Instances to run it, fits your use case quite nicely, no execution time limit and you only pay for the time the container is running (as opposed to WebJobs where you'll need to pay for the full hosting month) - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the topic.

Comment: You need table storage and you need to break up your processes into parallelizeable units of work. You can basically do what you need out of the box. Look up function bindings into table storage

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' how do you know his sql database can be easily moved to a nosql store? And also, azure functions has a processing limit for 10 minutes unless you go for a dedicated app service plan, in which case there are other alternatives. What you describe is a possible next step in the evolution of the app.

Comment: What single operation are you doing that requires over a few minutes?

Comment: Scraping data from websites

Answer (score 3):

You have some options.

[**Web Job**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

The name web job does not imply it must be a process with a frontend. So yes, it can be a console app (.exe) that is scheduled once a day. You pay for the underlying provisioned [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans).

[**Azure Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function#create-an-azure-function-app)

You can create a timer triggered azure function that will run some code. If the maximum processing time is 10 minutes you can use the [pay-per-use model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan) in which you only pay for the resources while the function is running.

If you cannot refactor it or split up into multiple functions each taking max. 10 minutes you have to provision an [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan) just like using a Web Job.

[**Azure Container Instances**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/)

If you can put your console app into a container you can use Azure Container Instances to spin up a container once a day and tear it down once the job is done. You will only pay for the resources used when the container is up and running.

**My opinion**

Since you have a job running once a day for approximately one hour I'd say go for Azure Container Instances as you will only pay for the time the container (job) is running.

If the process would take less then 10 minutes I would personally go for Azure Functions hosted on a consumption plan (pay-per-use model) as it is the cheapest option I know.

Comment: I need to check what is the differences between them.
What if I use SQL server DB with this solution?

Comment: Using sql server won't be a problem depending on where the database is hosted. I suggest using [Azure Sql Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-index)

Comment: Absolutely, Thanks for the comment!